# When do limits of $R$-modules commute with direct sum?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Is there any good special case in which I can say that a limit of $R$-modules commutes with direct sum? This is of course true for finite direct sums. Are there other criteria?